# Dr.Memory crashes when used on SDL program

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-1.2, dr-memory

I am working on a SDL 1.2 project (Windows, C, Code::Blocks, also using sdl_tff library). I am trying to check memory leaks with Dr.Memory, but the problem I am having is that it crashes on start (log provided below),

The exe itself crashes on its own, and once I add the tff file I used to its directory, it runs fine on its own.

It does not matter where the 2 files are as long as they are both in the same directory, the exe runs fine.

How do I get Dr.Memory to execute properly?

```
Dr. Memory version 1.8.0 build 8 built on Sep  9 2014 16:27:02
Dr. Memory results for pid 6168: "SDL_Project.exe"
Application cmdline: ""C:\CodeBlocks Projects\projectrepo\SDL_Project\bin\Debug\SDL_Project.exe""
Recorded 108 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin\suppress-default.txt

Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x00000000-0x00000004 4 byte(s)
# 0 SDL_ttf.dll!?             +0x0      (0x6f4c2a9d <SDL_ttf.dll+0x2a9d>)
# 1 SDL_ttf.dll!?             +0x0      (0x6f4c2e1f <SDL_ttf.dll+0x2e1f>)
# 2 SDL_ttf.dll!?             +0x0      (0x6f4c3253 <SDL_ttf.dll+0x3253>)
# 3 createText                 [C:/CodeBlocks Projects/projectrepo/SDL_Project/menu.c:99]
# 4 startMenu                  [C:/CodeBlocks Projects/projectrepo/SDL_Project/menu.c:70]
# 5 SDL_main                   [C:/CodeBlocks Projects/projectrepo/SDL_Project/main.c:68]
# 6 console_main               [C:/CodeBlocks Projects/projectrepo/SDL_Project/menu.c:279]
# 7 WinMain@16                 [C:/CodeBlocks Projects/projectrepo/SDL_Project/menu.c:279]
# 8 main                       [../../../../src/gcc-4.7.1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:185]
Note: @0:00:08.932 in thread 2912
Note: instruction: mov    (%edi) -> %edx

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      1 unique,     1 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     82 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-SDL_Project.exe.6168.000\potential_errors.txt)
    183 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-SDL_Project.exe.6168.000\potential_errors.txt)
     12 unique,    18 total,    323 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-SDL_Project.exe.6168.000\results.txt
```

Comment: Apparently the program *needs* the font file (and, might I add, is badly written if it crashes for that reason!). You may need to tell Dr.Memory to start in the executable's folder, rather than calling the program from within Dr.M.'s folder.

Comment: i think you are right, i found out that running `path_to_dr_mem _path to exe`  fails, as does drag and dropping the exe on `Dr. Memory (drag your app here)` icon.  but drag and dropping the exe on the actual `drmemory.exe` worked, is there an argument to accomplish that?

Comment: That'd be `/full_path_to_drmemory/drmemory.exe sdl_exe`, from within the correct folder for your program. There is no UI equivalent, use a console.