# Dr Memory will not run with SDL ttf (2.0.10)

Tags: sdl, dr-memory

Upon adding SDL_ttf (2.0.10), DrMemory refuses to work anymore. The console went from printing out the messages to outputting nothing and sending the following to stdout:

```
~~Dr.M~~ WARNING: unable to locate results file: can't open D:\DrMemory
\drmemory\logs/resfile.6188 (code=2). Dr. Memory failed to start the 
target application, perhaps due to interference from invasive security 
software. Try disabling other software or running in a virtual machine.
```

Is there any way around this with some command line flag for Dr Memory or will I have to forego using Dr Memory?

Note: It works *perfectly fine* with other SDL stuff until I add the TTF Library and add a `TTF_Font *font` somewhere. The code I have works fine and there is no loading errors or anything wrong with it, it's at a very primitive level and fresh/new. I just cannot get Dr Memory to work as soon as any TTF element is added to the source code.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794463/dr-memory-crashes-when-used-on-sdl-program

Comment: @2501 Sadly the proposed solutions in that thread do not help.

Comment: If you're certain this is an issue with Dr.Memory, you should create a SSCCE and contact official support.

Comment: @2501 By official support do you mean post on the github issue tracker?

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to replicate the problem and make it really easy for the developer to replicate it as well, otherwise the problem isn't reproducible and solvable.

Answer (score 1):

It works with a 32-bit build, but not a 64-bit build... so I switched to using 32-bits.

Since this is not a full answer as to why. However if anyone finds it breaking for them, try 32-bit.